# How to use variables inside an MVEL expression?

Tags: java, mvel

I have pre-defined variables in my Java code which I want to use inside an MVEL expression. I don't want to pass a context.

```
String Col1 = "C";
String Col2 = "D";
String expression = "Col1 == 'C' &amp;&amp; Col2 == 'D'";

Boolean result = (Boolean) MVEL.eval(expression);
```

How do I read the variable values and evaluate the expression to true or false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add your variables, `col1` and `col2` to a context object and then pass this object to `MVEL.eval`. Given below is the working example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.mvel2.MVEL;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        String col1 = "C";
        String col2 = "D";

        context.put("col1", col1);
        context.put("col2", col2);

        String expression = "col1 == 'C' && col2 == 'D'";
        Boolean result = (Boolean) MVEL.eval(expression,context);
        System.out.println(result);//true

        expression = "col1 == 'E' && col2 == 'D'";
        result = (Boolean) MVEL.eval(expression,context);
        System.out.println(result);//false
    }
}
```

Feel free to let me know in case you have any further doubt.

**Update:** the following update is to explain why you need the context object (you have mentioned in your comment that you do not want to add your variables to a context object).

If you look into the documentation at https://github.com/mvel/mvel/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mvel2/MVEL.java, you will be tempted to use the following method:

```
public static Object eval(String expression) {
    return new MVELInterpretedRuntime(expression, new ImmutableDefaultFactory()).parse();
}
```

However, the following piece of code will fail to compile:

```
String col1 = "C";
String col2 = "D";
String expression = "col1 == 'C' && col2 == 'D'";
System.out.println(new MVELInterpretedRuntime(expression, new ImmutableDefaultFactory()).parse());
```

The reason for this is, the visibility of the following constructor is not `public`.

```
MVELInterpretedRuntime(String expression, VariableResolverFactory resolverFactory) {
    setExpression(expression);
    this.variableFactory = resolverFactory;
}
```

So, you need to populate a context object in your client program and pass this object, along with the expression, to the program/method evaluating MVEL expression. In my program, it is the `main` method where I am populating the context object as well as evaluating the MVEL expression.

Comment: I would do that but the expression will not always be the same. It will probably change in the future. And I don't want to keep changing the Java code modifying the map every time the expression changes. Actually, I am storing the expression in a database table and evaluating the expression in Java. So the Java code doesn't change at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Arvind. I created a dynamic map and passed it to eval method.